# Unity3D: Rendering images weirdly in GUISkin

Tags: unity

So i'm trying to make a gui skin in Unity3D and i'm having some problems with the images, what I mean is the images are being rendered all weirdly, not properly and some have lines through them. I have some photos of what is happening.

Background (GUI Box)
[image]

Button (GUI Button)

[image]

Anyone know why the images are being rendered weirdly and how to fix it? Appreciate any help!